# How do Flutter app store lists for dropdown if there are more than 100 options?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown, flutter-hive

Am pretty new to the Flutter & Dart environment and would like some advice on how to store dropdown lists with selectable items 30-100 items long. Some dropdown lists are filtered by other dropdown fields as well.

Would the best advice be to use a local database or would it be better to implement it as a const List? If storing it locally would be better would you recommend using Hive with an put(0,"brandNameList ": "default 1", "itemNameList" : ["item1","item2","item3"])?

Just to add further, this would not be the values returned from the dropdown list.

Thanks for any advice.

sample code would be similar to this:
[how to filter json from dropdown in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672240/how-to-filter-json-from-dropdown-in-flutter)

but I would like the json lists to be for example: (where brandName filters the itemsList available)

```
List<Map> brandNameList = [
  {"id": 0, "brandNameList ": "default 1", "itemNameList" : ["item1","item2","item3"]},
  {"id": 1, "brandNameList ": "default 2", "itemNameList" : ["item4","item5","item10"]},
  .
  .
  .
  {"id": 60, "name": "default 60"}, "itemNameList" : ["item4","item5","item10"]},
];
```

Sample results:

```
If brandName == "default 5" then show itemNameList list of values which is ["item4","item5","item10"]
```

Comment: Can you share your expected result?

Comment: @Diwyansh I've added the sample expected results, would you have any advice on this? Thanks